# Sublime text: How to get rid of the extra "window"

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I use Sublime-text to type LaTeX on a Ubuntu Machine.

My sublime currently looks like

[image]

And I want to get rid of the extra "window" on the right, as it was before. I don't know why this happened, probably because I've played with some other packages...

Answer (score 1):

You have two column layout enabled.

You can disable it in *View* → *Layout* → *Single*.

Or, alternatively, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (<kbd>2</kbd> will re-enable it).